# Need to use an array in another class.. error is arrayXYZ undeclared!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, inheritance

i have a class **abcParser** in which i have an array **arrayXYZ**. Now i need to use this array in a **viewController**.. when i do so it gives an error.. **arrayXYZ undeclared**

i m weak in inheritance, please help!
thanks!!

Comment: This sounds like you lack a proper understanding of the object oriented approach in objective-c, I recommend you read "Learning Objective-C: A primer" http://bit.ly/a3pl89 and "The Objective-c programming language" http://bit.ly/g1s0Iu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a function in ABCParser that lets you retrieve the array, like so:

```
-(NSArray *)arrayXYZ:(NSString *)anArgument{
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:anArgument];

    return array;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Alright, seems like we need a little lesson on instantiation etc...

Now, those Plus (+) and Minus (-) signs beside method names...

Plus is a class method. It can be used without instantiation, but understand that variables cannot be carried over when you use these.

Instance methods require you to instantiate a new object, then ask it to perform methods.

```
ABCParser *parser = [[ABCParser alloc] init];
```

That creates a new 'instance' of ABCParser and makes a pointer to it with the name 'parser'. That's all fine and dandy.

When we want this new parser object to do something, we tell it as normal:

```
NSArray *myNewArray = [parser arrayXYZ];
```

**So - When you have an instance of your class, do this:**

```
ABCParser *parser = [[ABCParser alloc] init];

[parser generateArrayXYZ];
NSArray *array = [parser getArrayXYZ];
```

This will give you an object that you can work with. It'll take a bit of getting used to, but you'll learn. If you need any further explanation, just post :)

Comment: how should i call that function from viewController??

Comment: thank you very much it helped a lot..  can i contact you for my silly doubts?? :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you already add @property and @syntesize to your NSArray variable in abcParser?